# typescript isn't removing import when compiling to ES5

Tags: typescript

I have a typescript file that uses moment and I need to import moment for it to compile, but the compiled file kept the import line which is annoying my web page.

This is my tsconfig file:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
        "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [
            "es2015",
            "dom"
        ],
            "module": "es2015",
             "moduleResolution": "node",
             "noEmitOnError": true,
             "outDir": "Assets/Scripts/lib",
             "pretty": true,
             "removeComments": true,
             "rootDir": "tsSrc",
             "target": "es5",
             "sourceMap": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "tsSrc/typescript-definitions"
    ]
}
```

example of how its being used:

```
/// <reference path="../../../node_modules/moment/moment.d.ts" />
import * as moment from "moment";

console.log(moment().format("M/D/YYYY h:mm a"));
```

Comment: If you use values (not only types) imported with `import` in `.ts` file, you have to make imported module available at runtime. You can compile with `"module": "amd"` and use module loader, for example requirejs, or compile with `"module": "commonjs"` and use a bundler, for example webpack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specified `"module": "es2015"`, and `import` statements are ES2015 module syntax. Specify whichever module loader you're using instead (`amd`, `commonjs`)